# How to find if mapkit failes to acquire user location?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, user-location

In my app I'm using map kit.The map kit is working fine but sometimes it fails to acquire user location,so i thought i could show en error message but when i applied the error message it prompting again and again looking very annoying.so i want to ask that when map kit starts to get current user location and if it fails how do i show an error message something like this "Maps unable to determine your current location please try after sometime" then hide the message and show it after sometime if it again fails to acquire user location or if it gets the user location then do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CLLocationManager to find user's location? It has one pretty delegate method that, I think, will be helpful in your case.

> ```
> - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
> ```

Comment: i don't want to use location manager because i must show default blue dot of mapkit.

Comment: it's fine to use both.  if the CLLocationManager fails, mapkit will as well.

Comment: @Carl Coryell-Martin
hello,no i am getting location from cllocation manager but not getting the blue dot.

Comment: you need to turn on the showsUserLocation property of your MKMapView to have the blue dot show up.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the map kit in my app and when i increase the span of the map it shows crash on iphone.